# Footer will not stay at the bottom of one of my pages

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 100%;
}


/*----------------------Header Styling------------------------------------*/

header {
 background-color: white;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 overflow: auto;
 height: 200px;
 font-family: "Freehand521 BT", Arial, Sans-serif;
}

header p {
 font-family: "Freehand521 BT", Arial, Sans-serif;
 margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
 font-size: 60px;

}

header img {
 float: right;
 border-left: solid;
}

/*-------------------------------Main Nav Styling--------------------------------*/

#mainlinks {
 margin-top: 60px;
}

#mainlinks ul {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#mainlinks a {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 margin-right: 90px;
 margin-left: -10px;
 font-size: 25px;
}

#mainlinks li {
 display: inline;
 padding-right: 5px;
}

/*----------------------------------Secondary Nav Styling----------------------------------------------------*/


.secondlinks li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.secondlinks ul {
 padding-left: 0px;
}


/*-------------------------------------Main Content Styling--------------------------------------------------------*/

#contentwrap {
 background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, .7);
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 padding: 15px;
 font-family: "Freehand521 BT", Arial, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;

}

#contentwrap img {
 border-style: solid;

}
/*-------------------------------------------Footer Styling------------------------------------------------------*/

footer {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-top-style: solid;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 130px;
 font-family: "Freehand521 BT", Arial, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
}

#footernav {
 float: right;
}

#footernav li {
 display: inline;
}

#footernav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-right: 30px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Defenders Of The Stars!--The Official Sailor Moon Fanpage!</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/SM.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <img src="images/HeaderSilouette.png" alt="Defenders Of The Stars Header" width="200" height="200">
  <p>Defenders of the stars!</p>
  <nav id="mainlinks">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="ss.html">Sailor Senshi</a></li>
    <li><a href="villains.html">Villains</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <div id="contentwrap">
  <h1> Welcome Fans!</h1>
  <p>Welcome to the Official Sailor Moon Fanpage! Here you will find a lot of information about the Sailor Moon Universe! Including Characters and villains alike, As well as an overview of the story so far. We will also keep this Page updated with the latest happenings in the world of Sailor Moon!</p>
  <p><u>July 5 2014</u> - New Sailor Moon Anime, Sailor Moon Crystal is released!</p>
 </div>
 <footer>
  <p id ="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2016 Jorge Goris.<br />Designed and developed by Jorge Goris.</p>
  <nav id="footernav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="ss.html">Sailor Senshi</a></li>
    <li><a href="villains.html">Villains</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code snippet. In my main page I keep getting a little bit of space underneath my footer. Setting a height seems to have worked for the other pages because they have a lot of content. My main page however does not so the footer does not go all the way down. I've tried so many different ways to get this correct and I cannot seem to do it. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to `#contentwrap`:

```
padding-bottom: 130px; 
min-height: 100%;
```

And this to `footer`:

```
position: relative;
margin-top: -130px;
clear: both;
```

If you change the height of the footer later, change the values above accordingly. [Working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrVJjz)

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked! going to save this piece of code for later use since this footer situation has been a hassle for all the pages I've tried to create. Thanks again!

Comment: Now I have some space from the header up top and the content. How would I create that same amount of space between my content and footer?

Comment: @Fate you mean so that there is a rounded border at the bottom of the content, above the footer (like at the top)?

Comment: Well between my main Navigation at the top and my content there is some margin. How do I create that same amount of space between my content and footer?

Comment: @fate add `margin-bottom: 150px;` to `#contentwrapper` (height of footer + 20px)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this on the outer footer element:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

You can use padding, or continue to use the `bottom` property to further adjust the position. The number entered in the bottom property should include `px` if you bring it above 0 (i.e. "`5px`"). This value is pixels /from/ the bottom, so adding more will push it up.

Comment: This is incorrect, due to the fact that if the content is larger than the screen, and the user scrolls. the footer will scroll with the content

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the footer styling and remove the height property:

> height: 130px;

this will allow the footer to adjust it's own height.

Comment: That is incorrect, since the OP is looking to place the footer at the bottom of the screen,

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to fix the footer to the bottom, 
Be sure to use a unique class if this behaviour is only for one page.

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If the content is larger than the available space, you could also add

```
body {
   padding-bottom: 130px; // the height of the footer
}
```

alternatively, you should explore using flexbox to build your UI along with some fallbacks. 
here is a nice article https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This code works for fixing the footer to the bottom of the screen, but OP wants to put it on the bottom of the **document**, while adding whitespace between the content and the footer for lager screens so there is no whitespace between the bottom of the footer and the bottom of the screen.